# <span class="blinking"> is not working in javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<body class="container-fluid">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3>Body Temperature</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <p>Your body temperature is higher than normal:
        <span class="blinking">
    <script>
    let tempFahrenheit=99;
    const NORMAL_FAHREN=98.6;
    let tempCelsius;
    const THIRTYTWO=32;
    const TEMP=1.8;
    tempCelsius=(tempFahrenheit-THIRTYTWO)/TEMP;
    let fever=tempFahrenheit>NORMAL_FAHREN;
    document.write(fever);
    document.write("</br>");
    document.write("Temp in celsius");
    </script>
     </span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I expect blinking to show up in chrome output but not seeing anything. Can anyone suggest whats issue with my code?

Comment: Any errors or other output in the console (press F12)?

Comment: F12 shows no issues in console.

Comment: Have you intentionally put the `<script>` tag inside a `<span>`?

Comment: Run the snippet in question and you'll see that it's working

Comment: I intentionally put <script> inside span tag.

Also
When i run code snippet, i dont see it blinking.

Should not i expect last line to be blinking like somewhat yellow colour:

Your body temperature is higher than normal: true
Temp in celsius true

Comment: I realised my problem. My blinking class codes was not done properly:

here is my blinking class:
.blinking{
    animation:blinkingText 1.8s infinite;
    background-color: yellow;
    color: red;
}
@keyframes blinkingText{
    0%{     color: #000;    }
    49%{    color: transparent; }
    50%{    color: transparent; }
    99%{    color:transparent;  }
    100%{   color: #000;    }
}

Comment: Thank you All. its now working properly.

The link href to blinking.class was not picking it properly because file was moved to another part that was another issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add some CSS code for blinking class

```css
.blinking {
        animation: blinker 0.6s linear infinite;
        color: #1c87c9;
      }
      @keyframes blinker {
        50% {
          opacity: 0;
        }
      }
```

```html
<body class="container-fluid">
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3>Body Temperature</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p>Your body temperature is higher than normal:
                <span class="blinking">
            <script>
            let tempFahrenheit=99;
            const NORMAL_FAHREN=98.6;
            let tempCelsius;
            const THIRTYTWO=32;
            const TEMP=1.8;
            tempCelsius=(tempFahrenheit-THIRTYTWO)/TEMP;
            let fever=tempFahrenheit>NORMAL_FAHREN;
            document.write(fever);
            document.write("</br>");
            document.write("Temp in celsius");
            </script>
             </span>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </body>
```

Comment: .blinking{
    animation:blinkingText 1.8s infinite;
    background-color: yellow;
    color: red;
}
@keyframes blinkingText{
    0%{     color: #000;    }
    49%{    color: transparent; }
    50%{    color: transparent; }
    99%{    color:transparent;  }
    100%{   color: #000;    }
}